# How to pass parameter in <rich:autocomplete>

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I need to pass a parameter in rich:autocomplete. So I did it like this.

```
<rich:autocomplete mode="ajax" minChars="2" var="message"   
                  fetchValue="#{message.displayName}" layout="div" 
                   autocompleteMethod="#{suggestionControlAction.suggestionAction}">
    <f:param name="param" value="KeyQueryVal"/>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{message.displayName}"/>
    </h:column>
 </rich:autocomplete>
```

And I am retrieving parameter value in my action class's suggestionAction method using,

```
Map<String, String> requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                               getExternalContext ().getRequestParameterMap();
String queryFor = requestMap.get("param");
```

But it's returning NULL.

In Richfaces 3, I used suggestionbox in the same way and able to pass the parameter but in Richface 4, this component is replaced by autocomplete and I am not able to achieve the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<a4j:param name="param" assignTo="#{BackingBean.property}"></a4j:param>
```

change `BackingBean` to your bean and `property`

Comment: <a4j:param> will not work since it require a parent componenat as Ajax.It gives a compile time error.